# Working on my portfolio/CV site, but the menu isn't hovering like I want it to

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm fairly new to coding and new to this website c:
I've been following the SheCodes courses and I'm currently doing the Responsive one because I want to move my coding career in that direction.
Anyways, I'm working on my own website to display my Illustration works and whatnot https://mariafloscher.netlify.app/ but the menu isn't hovering the way I want it, I want the whole section to look white and not only the area surrounding the words.

Here's the GitHub repository https://github.com/mariafloscher/cv-and-portfolio

Here's the HTML portion of the menu:

```
<div id="menu">
        <div><a href="index.html" class="menu-item">homepage</a></div>
        <div><a href="pages/about.html" class="menu-item">about</a></div>
        <div><a href="pages/work-experience.html" class="menu-item">work experience</a></div>
        <div><a href="pages/works.html" class="menu-item">works</a></div>
        <div><a href="pages/commissions-hiring.html" class="menu-item">commissions' & hiring info</a></div>
        <div><a href="pages/contact.html" class="menu-item">contact</a></div>
    </div>
```

And here's the CSS

```
#menu { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-color: #202020;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    height: fit-content;
}


.menu-item {
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-color: #202020;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    color: #202020;
}

.menu-link {
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-color: #202020;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-link:hover {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    color: #202020;
    text-decoration: none;
    max-width: max-content;
}
```

Thanks in advance <3 Have a great day and a good start of the week :D!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you don't need the `<div>` tag around your `<a>` tags.

```
<div id="menu">
       <a href="index.html" class="menu-item">homepage</a>
       <a href="pages/about.html" class="menu-item">about</a>
       <a href="pages/work-experience.html" class="menu-item">work experience</a>
       <a href="pages/works.html" class="menu-item">works</a>
       <a href="pages/commissions-hiring.html" class="menu-item">commissions' & hiring info</a>
       <a href="pages/contact.html" class="menu-item">contact</a>
</div>
```

If you want to see hover animation over the whole menu-item, you have to remove padding form `#menu` and add it instead to `.menu-item`. Also use `flex: 1 1 auto;` if you using `display: flex;` for `#menu` if you.

```
#menu { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-color: #202020;  
    height: fit-content;
}


.menu-item {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-color: #202020;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    color: #202020;
}

.menu-link {
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-color: #202020;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-link:hover {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    color: #202020;
    text-decoration: none;
    max-width: max-content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `menu-item` from `a` to `div` and in css

1. On menu item add `flex: 1`. That will make sure that all items are stretched to max available space
2. Add `.menu-item a` and `.menu-item:hover a` to handle menu items properly

Side note:
You can add `column-gap: 10px` to `#menu` or `padding: 0 5px` on `.menu-item` in order add more space between elements. Use both and you will see the difference.

Here is full example

```css
#menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-color: #202020;
    height: fit-content;
}


.menu-item {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #202020;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-item a {
    color: #f8f8f8;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.menu-item:hover a {
    color: #202020;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="index.html">homepage</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="pages/about.html">about</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="pages/work-experience.html">work experience</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="pages/works.html">works</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="pages/commissions-hiring.html">commissions' & hiring info</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="pages/contact.html">contact</a></div>
</div>
```